# Как подсчитать количество файлов и папок в папке?

Tags: c

```
int count_files(char *dir)
{
struct dirent *entry;
DIR *dp;
struct stat statbuf;
mode_t modes;
int papka=0, file=0;

if ((dp = opendir(dir)) == NULL) 
{
    printf("cannot open directory: %s\n", dir);
    exit(0);
}
while (entry = readdir(dp))
{
    stat(entry -> d_name, &statbuf);
    modes = statbuf.st_mode;
    if (strcmp(".", entry->d_name) == 0 || strcmp ("..", entry->d_name) == 0){continue;}
    printf("%s ", entry->d_name);
    if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
    {
        papka++;
        printf ("papka %d \n", papka);
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        file++;
        printf("file %d \n", file);
        continue;
    }
}
printf("Papok:%d, faylov:%d", papka, file);
return papka;
}
```

Функция работает некорректно, считает папки и файлы рандомно, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Что значит "рандомно"? Создаёт произвольные файлы-папки и их считает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эх, проще заново переписать.

```
#include <dirent.h>

int file_count = 0;
int dir_count = 0;
int total = 0;

DIR * dirp;
struct dirent * entry;

dirp = opendir("path"); 
while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
    total++;
    if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) {
         file_count++;
    }
}
dir_count = total - file_count;
closedir(dirp);
```

Обработку ошибок, заголовок, вывод учет или не учет папок `.` и `..`, скрытых файлов и символических ссылок предлагаю дописать в учебных целях самостоятельно.

P.S. Через bash подсчет числа файлов в папке делается значительно проще:

`ls -1 | wc -l`  файлы и папки

`ls -1d */ | wc -l` только папки